# .so module doesnt import in python: dynamic module does not define init function

Tags: c++, python, c, python-c-api, python-extensions

I am trying to write a python wrapper for a C function. After writing all the code, and getting it to compile, Python can't import the module. I am following the example given [here](http://csl.sublevel3.org/C-functions-from-Python/). I reproduce it here, after fixing some typos. There is a file myModule.c:

```
#include <Python.h>

/*
 * Function to be called from Python
 */
static PyObject* py_myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    char *s = "Hello from C!";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}
/*
 * Bind Python function names to our C functions
 */
static PyMethodDef myModule_methods[] = {
    {"myFunction", py_myFunction, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

/*
 * Python calls this to let us initialize our module
 */
void initmyModule()
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("myModule", myModule_methods);
}
```

Since I am on a Mac with Macports python, I compile it as

```
$ g++ -dynamiclib -I/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers -lpython2.6 -o myModule.dylib myModule.c
$ mv myModule.dylib myModule.so
```

However, I get an error when I try to import it.

```
$ ipython
In[1]: import myModule
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)

/Users/.../blahblah/.../<ipython console> in <module>()

ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initmyModule)
```

Why can't I import it?

Comment: Your code seems to be a bit garbled.

Comment: @Ignacio: I am just trying to follow the examples. Is there a simpler example you could point me to?

Comment: Does the code in the top box really reflect what you have in your source file?

Comment: @Ignacio. Sorry, you're right. It messed up when I copied it from the file. I recopied the code. It now reflects what I have in my source file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using a C++ compiler, function names will be [mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) (for instance, my `g++` mangles `void initmyModule()` into `_Z12initmyModulev`). Therefore, the python interpreter won't find your module's init function.

You need to either use a plain C compiler, or force C linkage throughout your module with an [extern "C"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.4) directive:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif 

#include <Python.h>

/*
 * Function to be called from Python
 */
static PyObject* py_myFunction(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    char *s = "Hello from C!";
    return Py_BuildValue("s", s);
}

/*
 * Bind Python function names to our C functions
 */
static PyMethodDef myModule_methods[] = {
    {"myFunction", py_myFunction, METH_VARARGS},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

/*
 * Python calls this to let us initialize our module
 */
void initmyModule()
{
    (void) Py_InitModule("myModule", myModule_methods);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif
```

Comment: The `PyMODINIT_FUNC` macro as given in the documentation will handle this for you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Could you please elaborate how to carry out your solution? Thanks.